# create the collections and indexes in symfony ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, collections

create the collections and indexes you can run:

php app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create

schema update

php app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update

Note: you can see other commands:
php app/console doctrine:mongodb

Answer (score 0):

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Document\Post:
    repositoryClass: Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\PostMongoRepository
    type: document
    collection: post_test
    fields:
        id:
            id:  true
        title:
            type: string
            index: asc

# php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AcmeDemoBundle
# Create Document
# php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:repositories AcmeDemoBundle
# Create repository
```

now run php app/console doctrine:mongodbdb:schema:update

Answer (score 0):

```
// AppBundle/Document

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProduitRepository")
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="$noProduit")
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex(order="asc")
     */
    protected $noProduit;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $libelle;
// getter and setter
}

// AppBundle/Controller

$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$dm->getSchemaManager()->ensureIndexes();
```

schema and database will be created automatically when you run your app.
For more info [visit this link](http://blog.servergrove.com/2010/10/07/creating-indexes-for-your-doctrine-odm-documents-with-symfony-2/)